# Magento extremely slow

Tags: magento2, cache, performance, slow-response, gtmetrix

[image: watertfall]My server TTFB wait time is 14 seconds ,
Total loading time is 24.5 seocnds

I have attached my waterfall for GT metrix:

How can I deal with it ??

I am done with following :

1. I have minified css and JS
2. Enabled Flat category
3. Production mode is enabled
4. Cloudfront images are enabled
5. Upgraded Magento version
6. Advance JS bundling

The whole store is slow but the product page is extremely slow.

Shall I go for Full page cache warmer extension?

Should I configure Varnish & redis ?

I am also done with advance JS bundling  It reduces only 4 to 5 seconds

Kindly suggest solutions!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you have `14sec` TTFB this is related to your code processing time, check profiler or newrelic,
probably you are trying to load something big on that page.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html

> js bundle is bad